# CAGradientLayer overflows on UIView when using in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cagradientlayer

I've add CAGradientLayer to a `UIView` that've already inside in `UITableViewCell`. This UIView has 20 `trailing` and `leading` space from the `UITableViewCell` `contentView`. But that UIView's overflow when it running.

```
var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer!

@IBOutlet weak var view: UIView!

    func createGradientLayer() {
        gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer.init(layer: view.layer)
        gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
        //        gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.contentView.frame.size.width, height: )

        let colory: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 189/255, blue: 237/255, alpha: 1.0)

        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.ceruleanBlue.cgColor, colory.cgColor]

        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x:1.0,y: 0.5)

//        self.view.layer.mask = gradientLayer
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
```

Then in the cellForRow method, I used like this:

```
if indexPath.row == 0{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "statisticsCell") as! StatisticsCommentCell

//            cell.frame.size.width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
            cell.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return cell
        }
```

If I changed gradientLayer.frame like below:

```
gradientLayer.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width
```

the gradientView is not overflow but there seems just `ceruleanBlue` color.

I do not any idea how can I solve this problem for my `UIView`.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Its a screenshot from the simulator that have overflow problem:

Hint: Normally the `UIView` has already trailing and leading from the `UITableViewCell`'s `contentView`.

[image]

Another problem is when I add maskToBounds the view seems like below

[image]

All constraints for `UIView`

[image]

Comment: can you post an image of your issue?

Comment: @ReinierMelian edited the question

Comment: did you have width constraint's IBoutlet of this view? can you show screenshot with all constraints of this view on storyboard

Comment: add maskToBounds = true in your view

Comment: @ReinierMelian I've just added maskToBounds but UIView has not gradient anymore, is it normal?

Comment: @SergeyHleb nope, just have trailings, leadings and also top bottom anchors.

Comment: how did you added? @elia you should add self.view.layer.maskToBounds = tru

Comment: I've added like what you said, in cell file.

Comment: remove this line gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height), and let me know

Comment: @ReinierMelian deleted it already but just seems ceruleanBlue color, I think its not normal ?

Comment: @SergeyHleb I've added screenshot.

Comment: try to use layoutIfNedeed() for your view, before adds gradient layer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your gradientLayer as optional, instead of  `var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer!` use `var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer?` and add this code in your cellLayoutSubViews method

**Use this code**

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if(self.gradientLayer == nil){
    self.gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer(layer: self.view.layer)
    //your gradient configuration
    self.layer.addSublayer(self.gradientLayer!)
    }
    self.gradientLayer?.drawsAsynchronously = true
    self.gradientLayer?.frame = self.view.bounds
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @ReinlerMelian, so is the problem that synchronous drawing ?

Comment: no, its the `self.gradientLayer?.frame = self.view.bounds` in the `layoutSubviews`